# Slow mysql query full text search tag database

Tags: mysql, performance, full-text-search, subquery

Need some help with a query.
In the database are ~700k of images, each image has it's own tag(s).
I want to be able to search images by it's tags with a full text search query.
The query does exactly what i want but it's very slow.
Can some please help me speed to speed it up, or create an other one.
There a indexes on al the id-fields and the name field in de 'image_tag' table.

```
SELECT
    image.*
FROM image
INNER JOIN (SELECT image_to_tag.image_id,
             GROUP_CONCAT(image_tag.`name`) AS tags
        FROM image_to_tag
        INNER JOIN image_tag
        ON (image_tag.id = image_to_tag.image_tag_id)
    GROUP BY image_to_tag.image_id) t ON t.image_id = image.id
WHERE MATCH (t.tags) AGAINST ('+justin* +backgrounds*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Table: image

```
id | filename 
1  | image1.jpg
2  | image2.jpg
3  | image3.jpg
```

Table: image_to_tag

```
image_id | image_tag_id
1        | 1
1        | 2
2        | 3
2        | 4
```

Table: image_tag

```
id | name
1  | justin bieber
2  | backgrounds
3  | justin timberlake
4  | other backgrounds
```

If i search for "justin background" i want to find image 1 and 2.
If i search for "justin bieber background" i want to find image 1.

Comment: First, avoid using `*` in query.

Comment: Already tried that but it's not helping much, 0.1 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let me know if with this could be a little faster.

```
select id,filename from image
where id in(
    select image_id from image_to_tag a
    inner join image_tag b
    on b.id = a.image_tag_id and b.name like '%justin%'
)
```

Comment: It went from 1.7 to 1.4 sec.

Comment: @MichaelvandeRijt This is the fastest way that I know. Consider to ask about this in  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance

Comment: Just posted it there, hope some can help me. Thanks for your help!
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116291/slow-mysql-query-full-text-search-tag-database

Answer (score 0):

You can boost up the performance by splitting your query into three parts. It will give your results in milliseconds :

```
$tagids = '';    
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT group_concat(id) as tagids FROM image_tag WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('+justin* +backgrounds*' IN BOOLEAN MODE");
if($row = $res->fetch_object()){
  $tagids = $row->tagids;
}
$res->close();

$imageids = '';
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT group_concat(image_id) as imageids FROM image_to_tag WHERE image_tag_id in($tagids)");
if($row = $res->fetch_object()){
   $imageids = $row->imageids;
}
$res->close();

$imgarr = array();
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,filename FROM image WHERE id in($imageids)");
if($row = $res->fetch_object()){
   array_push($imgarr,$row);
}
$res->close();
echo json_encode($imgarr);
```